# How to persist new JSON object with many-to-one field by its ID?

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-boot, jpa

I'm new to Spring Boot and have quite annoying problem.

I have two related entities: Transaction and Category

**Category.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_categories")
public class Category extends BaseEntity {

  @Column(name = "category_name")
  private String name;
}
```

**Transaction.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_transactions")
public class Transaction extends BaseEntity {

  private String description;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn
  private Category category;
}
```

And when I want to add new category, I simply do POST request with JSON body like this:

```
{
  "name": "XYZ"
}
```

And new category is created (e.g. with ID 1). Now I want to add new Transaction with JSON like this:

```
{
  "description": "Qwerty",
  "category": 1
}
```

So I want to pass only ID of related object. Following error is thrown:

```
Cannot construct instance of `persistence.models.Category` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `persistence.models.Category` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1)\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 3, column: 12] (through reference chain: persistence.models.Category[\"parent\"])"
```

What should I do now? Searching this error gives inconclusive information. I'm new to this and it is quite puzzling.

Comment: https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-one-to-many-mapping-example/

Comment: you refer this site and do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "t_categories")
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "catId")
    public class Category extends BaseEntity {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        Long catId;

        @Column(name = "category_name")
        private String name;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "category")
        private Set<Transaction> transactions = new HashSet<>();
    }

    @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "t_transactions")
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = 
    ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "transId")
    public class Transaction extends BaseEntity {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       Long transId

        private String description;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "cat_id", nullable = false)
        private Category category;
    }

Generate setters and getters method then you try this code.
```

When you retrieve category or transactions. you will get recursion error. That is why I added this annotation.

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "catId")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, this is not solving my problem. I have all the code you mentioned (also with getters/setters generated by Lombok and IDs stored in BaseEntity). The problem is with parsing JSON and not resolving category by its ID

Comment: @KumaresanPerumal you answer is not complete, So how do you write your json ?